# How to Close a swing application properly

Tags: java, swing

I make a java swing application with some threads. When I pressed 'x' button in window, all running threads stopped and application close properly. But I want to close the application from java code. I used this.dispose(); for close the application. But when I used that method, window is closed. But all threads are still running. How I closed the application properly. please help me.

Comment: if you want to close whole application then, use System.exit(0) then also this frame will be closed

Comment: do also make the those extra threads as daemon thread

Comment: Thank u all of you for help me. System.exit(0); is worked as veritas says.

Comment: @KalanaSarange : If you are using `JFrame`, try to add this line `frameReference.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` now after pressing `X` Button, if still the situation arises, as described in the latter part of your question, then I guess, you need to revisit your code regarding threads. As your threads are not properly shutting down.

Comment: @KalanaSarange : Please refer to this answer regarding how to [close a Swing Application from the code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/258099/1057230) for more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `System.exit(0);` causes JVM kills the application silently, OR make other threads as [daemon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial#dtr)

Comment: Is this the proper way of closing an application ? I really don't think so :( It is very much like I go to my `Task Manager` and give command to kill my `process`

Comment: @nIcEcOw do you have better idea buddy? share, I just answered the question

Comment: @user2511414 : Please refer to the link I provided as a comment to OP's question.

Comment: @nIcEcOw it's about disposing the frame and gui components, not about other running threads :)

Comment: @user2511414 : Please see the title of the question... Your way is definitely not the right way then, if you considering threads. (That thingy wait for all the threads to be closed, before terminating the JVM).

Comment: @nIcEcOw _I make a java swing application with some *threads* . . . window is closed. But *all threads* are still running_ :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33546/discussion-between-nice-cow-and-user-2511414)

Comment: @user2511414 : To me it implies that, there lies the problem with the OP's code. So using `System.exit(0)`, the OP is not graciously closing the application. Can't say much in the absence of that code.

Comment: @nIcEcOw & user2511414 : According your conversation, I was really confused. because of nIcEcOw says System.exit(0) is like a process killer. then what should I do now? I don't know how to make the threads as daemon too. please give me some advise to resolve my problem.

Comment: @KalanaSarange : Please have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15676695/1057230), might be it can give you that slight idea, about the difference between the two approaches. Try to close the application after starting the thread, from the `X` button and then, first stop the thread and then press that `X` button :-) And do see how your command prompt reacts in both these situations :-)

Comment: @KalanaSarange : Instead try this [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbmifx4upc3tq2t/ThreadCounter.java), it is just a slight improved version of the latter, with text colours to tell the difference that the two threads are running :-) And yeah, do try to change `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` to `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, in the example and do see the difference, after applying the same closing way, as explained before. `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is same as using `System.exit(0)`

Comment: @KalanaSarange for daemon thread, take look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial#dtr) buddy, always beware about the `System.exit();` because if your thread(s) is writing or saving something, then an inconsistent state will appear, otherwise feel free to kill them, while JVM kills daemon silently if there is no ant thread available

Answer (score 1):

See [public static void exit(int status)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine.

But be careful when you use this in multi-threaded application.