# What prevents program from exiting?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

I wrote like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        while(true){
            try{
                // do something
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){
                System.out.println("ABC");
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1280,720);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

When I clicked "close" button of the window,
the program took few seconds to end.
What prevents program from exiting ?
And how can I close program immediately **without** using `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` ?

I think my thread (`while(true)` thread) ends immediately
because "ABC" is displayed soon after I clicked "close" button.

Thank you.

EDIT

same thing occured without my thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1280,720);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

EDIT2

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[5];
        Thread.enumerate(threads);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(threads));
        System.err.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " SHUTDOWN");
    }
    ));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1280,720);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
                Thread[] threads = new Thread[5];
                Thread.enumerate(threads);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(threads));
                System.err.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " CLOSE");
            }
        });
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

the output was:

```
[Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main], null, null, null]
2016-08-02T19:04:50.465 CLOSE
[Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main], Thread[Thread-0,5,main], null, null, null]
2016-08-02T19:04:51.762 SHUTDOWN
```

Comment: Is that your full code? Because `thread` needs to be initialized

Comment: I can not reproduce this. After fixing the compilation issues, `ABC` is immediately printed when clicking the close button and the program terminates. Please also review http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swing/2266/swing-hello-world#t=201608020924423960976 to see how to properly start a Swing application.

Comment: @Cir0X sorry , the code was arranged for clarity, I edited.

Comment: @AndreasFester  After `ABC` is printed, it took about 2 seconds to terminate.

Comment: Ok, that is a different story then. I added a system shutdown hook where I am printing the current time (like `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> System.err.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " SHUTDOWN") ));` and I also added a time stamp to the output of `ABC`. I suggest that you do the same to make the issue more obvious. With that, I am observing a delay of approx. 1,5 seconds between those outputs - which, in my opinion, is not even unusual due to cleanup actions of the VM

Comment: And, btw, this is completely independant of your secondary thread. The delay also occurs (without that thread) between the `windowClosed` event and the execution of the shutdown hook. You might want to simplify your code in the question accordingly.

Comment: @AndreasFester Thank you. I edited.  Before `System.out.println("ABC")` , I observed existing thread using `Thread.enumerate()` , and I observed three threads,  "Thread-1" (my second thread) , "AWT-EventQueue-0" ,and "DestroyJavaVM"

Comment: You might want to check if https://github.com/afester/CodeSamples/blob/master/Java/Swing/src/com/example/swing/ExitDelay.java reproduces our issue. Feel free to use it as [mcve] in your question if it is useful. If yes, also add the output so that everyone is aware of the time spans you are talking about.

Comment: @AndreasFester  Thank you.  It took about 1.3 secs.

Comment: @AndreasFester  "Thread-0" is shutdown hook,  so the cause is "DestroyJavaVM"  ... ?

Comment: See my comment to the answer below. The behavior you observe is documented.

Answer (score 6):

While `System.exit()` should generally be used with care, the [Swing documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) explicitly states that it is the right approach in scenarios as shown in the question:

> When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM)
>   is  disposed of, the VM may terminate. Note, however, that **there can
>   be a delay  before the program exits automatically**, and that under
>   some circumstances the  program might keep running. **It is quicker and
>   safer to explicitly exit the  program using `System.exit(int)`**.

The following example does not show the delay between the close operation and the shutdown hook. When removing the `System.exit(0)` call, a delay of approx. 1,3 seconds can be observed:

```
package com.example.swing;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ExitDelay {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> System.err.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " SHUTDOWN") ));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(1280,720);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                @Override
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
                    System.err.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " CLOSE");

                    // Do all required cleanup stuff.
                    // check that threads are done, close files, commit transactions etc.
                    // ...

                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            frame.setVisible(true);

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To exit your program immediately you can use `System.exit(0)`.

Like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        while(true){
            try{
                // do something
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){
                System.out.println("ABC");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1280,720);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: sorry, I don't want to use `System.exit(0)` ,because I want to end program with my thread appropriately terminated.

Comment: Thats very crude and makes the use of `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` useless.

Comment: @Shu S `System.exit(0)` doesn't look [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7082054/3014979) wrong in Swing

Comment: `System.exit` in that position is also bad, because there is another thread working.

Comment: @ShuS `System.exit(0)` [stops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) the currently running jvm

Comment: exactly ... and thats called "bad coding" since running threads get "killed", even if they're still writing to disk, for example

Comment: @specializt I don't think [so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17671552/3014979)

Comment: you ... just gave my own claim proof. Thank you - but your actual statement (*"i dont think so")* doesnt make any sense ...

Comment: @specializt Generally I agree that `System.exit()` should be used with care. However, the [Swing documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) explicitly says: `When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM) is disposed of, the VM may terminate. Note, however, that there can be a delay before the program exits automatically, and that under some circumstances the program might keep running. It is quicker and safer to explicitly exit the program using System.exit(int).` I would do that in the `windowClosed()` method though.

Comment: @AndreasFester Thank you very much.  So what I should do is ,  to check   all thread is appropriately terminated (with `thread.join()`) and call `System.exit` .

Comment: Yes. See my answer. Additionally, in a real application, I would encapsulate the termination logic in a separate method which first takes care of all required cleanup and finally calls `System.exit`.

Answer (score 0):

You use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` and that makes sense because `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` would use `System.exit` to close the jvm process with all active threads. A `JFrame` is a complex structure that uses some native calls to register callbacks for mouse events at your operating system. So a clean exit takes some time. Additionally the Garbage Collector needs some time to detect that the `AWT-Thread` that runs the `JFrame` is completely finish with the cleanup before he kills it. So I think 1.3 seconds is acceptable for a clean finish of your application.
But if you really want to do so you could force the end with another `Thread` that simply checks continuously if all running threads have finished work and all `JFrames` have beend disappeared. And if so it calls the big evil `System.exit`.

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // make your JFrame final
final Thread thread  = new Thread(() ...  // make your Thread final
```

and add this end checking thread

```
final Thread endChecker  = new Thread(() -> {            
    while(true){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
            if(!frame.isDisplayable() && !thread.isAlive())
                System.exit(0);                 
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
            break;
        }
    }           
});
endChecker.start();
```