# Java: How should I implement waiting so that Images render?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, deadlock, awt-eventqueue

I'm not sure I've really asked the question correctly...and I'm not even sure if I've relevantly phrased the question or not..So, I apologize in advance...but I'm quite stuck on this issue and appreciate all help.. Further, I'm frankly not an expert so...please be gentle, I'm not *trying* to be an idiot.

So, the point of my program, frankly, is a simple game, based off of a certain game show on TV which has lifelines.. This specific one is the "phone a friend" one... I have a quote on quote 'button' (really a `JPanel` that has a `MouseListener`). Once this button is pressed, I would like it to add, and paint a `JLabel` or `JPanel` onto the `JFrame`, whatever works to draw an animated gif (of a countdown) and to lock the other `Component`s until 30 seconds have occurred. For the reference, I am not using a `LayoutManager` at the moment...

The way I've been attempting to do this, is:

```
ImageIcon CountdownImg = new ImageIcon("countdown.gif");
JLabel CountdownLbl = new JLabel(CountdownImg);
this.getContentPane().add(CountdownLbl);
CountdownLbl.setLocation(200, 200);
CountdownLbl.setSize(new Dimension(CountdownImg.getIconWidth(), CountdownImg.getIconHeight()));

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + 30000) {
    ;
}
```

I know the problem exists with my `while` loop. Without the loop, the image renders successfully. With it, java waits until after the condition is met to render `CountdownLbl`. I've also tried creating another `JFrame` with a content pane that had the image, but (probably again, due to my own misunderstanding or poor threading..) but the Frame simply appears and does not render its contents. Sometimes while running it I notice that there is a `Image Fetcher` thread, I'm assuming that my very bad loop could be interfering with this thread, and that this thread is what is responsible for rendering my image.

So I guess the question should be...How can I really implement this...in a thread safe way? If that is correct?

Thank you for your time, patience and effort.

Comment: 1) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: *"also tried creating another `JFrame`"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread responsible for drawing the image icon is same as the thread which is executing the while loop in your case.There is something called EDT , event dispatcher thread which updates your swing UI.You are using the same EDT to wait the countdown.

You might want to look into this [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml)

**EDIT:**

Should have added more information : here it is , [Using SwingWorker & SwingUtilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java)

Comment: How will using `SwingUtilitis.invokeLater()` help?

Comment: So should I first add the `Component` to my content pane, and put the timer in the new `Thread` created by `SwingUtilitis.invokeLater()`?

Many thanks again

Comment: @user99672: before you go down the wrong path, please understand that while Tito certainly means well, `SwingUtilitis.invokeLater()` does *not* create a new thread and certainly doesn't create a thread background from the Swing event thread. In other words, **don't** use it for trying to create a background thread, but instead use a SwingWorker. It may be used *inside* of an already created background thread to queue code onto the Swing event thread, but again this is only useful if you already are working in a background thread, and you're not there yet.

Comment: Ah ok..thank you. I should not have assumed that it would create a `Thread`...In the meantime I'll try to read the javadoc for `SwingWorker` and see if it helps.

Comment: @user99672: read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the details on how to use a SwingWorker. If used correctly, and if you get your images correctly (I'd use `ImageIO.read(someResourceInputStream)`), it *will* work, trust me.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `SwingWorker` to download images in the background. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513), a single component is updated in `done()`, but you can `publish()` and `process()` images as they arrive. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17763395/230513) outlines the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're question is tagged AWT, I suggest that you use a [`MediaTracker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html) to load your images. See the docs for a good description of how to use this to wait until your images are loaded.

You can also try using [`ImageIO.read(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29) to retrieve a `BufferedImage`.

To create an `ImageIcon` from a URL, just use the constructor [`ImageIcon(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.net.URL%29).

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Yeah, I noticed that. The question is tagged AWT, though (and not Swing).