# Disable button on click before actionPerformed is completed java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, event-dispatch-thread

I have a button doing a long function, I want to disable this button after the user once click on it to in order to prevent him from clicking it again many times

The button gets disabled but the problem is after the function finished the button gets enabled again 
i tried to put `button.setEnabled(false);` in a new thread but it didn't work either

for testing this sample of code

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Integer.MAX_VALUE; j++) {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < Integer.MAX_VALUE; ii++) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: why don't you put "button.enabled(false)" to end of for loops, Please can you clear which function finish.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: @user217895  Because a) that is not the problem, and b) it would defeat the purpose of what the OP is trying to achieve!

Comment: @user217895 `button.enabled(false)` dose not exist in java

Comment: _The button gets disabled but the problem is after the function finished the button gets enabled again_ I tried running your code. The problem I encountered is the UI freezes. The button is still disabled after the function is executed contrary to your findings. Perhaps you missed some codes that causes the reenabling of the button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for long running background tasks. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513), the `startButton` action does `setEnabled(false)`, and the worker's `done()` implementation does `setEnabled(true)`.

Answer (score 2):

- everything wrapped in `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {` is done at one moment, (on the screen) when all code lines are executed, this is basic rule for AWT/Swing Listeners and EventDispatchThread
- you need to delay event in EDT by using

  1. short delay with Swing Timer,
  2. redirect rest of code (after `button.setEnabled(false);`) to `SwingWorker`, easiest to `Runnable#Thread`, note all output from `Runnable#Thread` to the already visible Swing GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater`
- proper of ways will be only using `Swing Action` and instead of locking the `JButton` to set `Action.setEnabled(false)` only

Comment: can you explain more ??

Comment: You might look at the program examined in this related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17759287/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It's tempting to think you could use a mouse listener to implement this. For example, to prevent you could use mouse released event or mouse clicked event of mouse listener. Inside that you could write `button.setEnable(false)`. Unfortunately, this also blocks the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: *"try it..."*  Try puting an upper case letter at the start of sentences, to make the message easier to read.  *"it will work..."*  It will fail even worse than what the code is currently doing, especially when the user navigates to the button and presses 'Enter' (i.e. no `MouseEvent` will be fired at all).

Comment: Blocking the EDT is not the solution to blocking the EDT.

Comment: not the best answer because it not working completely it disabled the button only in view but if you clicked it working because MousePressed,MouseReleased,MouseClicked working always either if the button disabled