# Disabling JButton after first click

Tags: java, arraylist, jbutton, actionlistener, point

I was able to create about 11 JButtons in a circle using this code......

```
    public class Beginner extends JPanel {
        private JButton quest;
        public Beginner() {

                  int n = 10; //no of JButtons
                  int radius = 200;
                  Point center = new Point (250, 250);

                  double angle = Math.toRadians(360 / n);

                  List <Point> points = new ArrayList<Point> ();

                  points.add(center);

                  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                      double theta = i * angle;

                      int dx = (int) (radius * Math.sin(theta));

                      int dy = (int) (radius * Math.cos(theta));

                      Point p = new Point (center.x + dx , center.y + dy);
                      points.add(p);
                  }

                  draw (points);                      
                  }
                   public void draw (List<Point> points) {

                       JPanel panels = new JPanel();

                       SpringLayout spring = new SpringLayout();
                       int count = 1;
                       for (Point point: points) {

                           quest = new JButton("Question " + count); //JButton is drawn about 10 times in a circle arragement
                           quest.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                            Font fonte = new Font("Script MT Bold", Font.PLAIN, 20);
                            quest.setFont(fonte);
                           add (quest);
                           count++;
                           ;
                           spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, quest, point.x, SpringLayout.WEST, panels );

                           spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, quest, point.y, SpringLayout.NORTH, panels );

                           setLayout(spring);

                           panels.setOpaque(false);
                           panels.setVisible(true);
                           panels.setLocation(10, 10);

                           add(panels);
}
}
}
```

Now, I have to create an actionListener for each JButton, and it is such each Button should be active only for one click, after which it changes its color to green!, I have no Idea on how to do that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable button on click befor actionPerformed is competed java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807846/disable-button-on-click-befor-actionperformed-is-competed-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a listener for all buttons:

**METHOD 1:**

```
    quest.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    source.setEnabled(false);
                    source.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
    });
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
    quest.addActionListener(new DisableButtonActionListener());

            ...

    private class DisableButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
                        source.setEnabled(false);
                        source.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }
    }
```

**METHOD 3 (my personal choise):**

```
Beginner implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    source.setEnabled(false);
                    source.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }

            ...

            quest.addActionListener(this);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am grateful!!

Comment: The First one worked very well, but I'll still keep the second in view, haven't tried it tho!.... But thanks again!

Comment: These 3 are doing the same thing, they are just written differently.

Answer (score 1):

In the button's action listener try to do:

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

It should work.

Comment: Nope!... That would generalize it and Disable the last button.......not the selected button!!