# why does my textArea not work in real time?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, while-loop, jtextarea

I am trying to append a string I get from my client program. However I made it so that the append statement is in a while loop. Does this have an affect in not working in real time?

For areas like

```
   tfFIXMsg.append( inputLine + "\n\n\n");
```

and

```
       tfCSVLine.append(outputLine+"\n\n\n");
```

It will not show the message on the textArea UNTIL the while loop is done. 
How can I make it so that it will continue to recieve messages from client, and be able to output it onto the textArea in realtime

```
try {
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
          { 
           System.out.println ("Server: " + inputLine); 


           tfFIXMsg.append( inputLine + "\n\n\n");


           int pos = inputLine.indexOf(inputLine, 0);
           h.addHighlight(50, 60, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);



           if (inputLine.trim().equals("Bye.")) {
               System.out.println("Exit program"); 
               break;
               } 

           Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));
           Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));
           Scanner input3 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));
           Scanner input4 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));


           String csvline = getCsvLineVal (getLocation34CSV(getTag34Value(Tag34Location(getTagCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine))), getValueCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine))), getVal34(input1,  input2)), getCSVLine( input3,  input4) );
           outputLine = compareClientFixCSV( getTagCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine)), getValueCSV(parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine)), getCSVTag(csvline), getCSVValue(csvline));

           out.println(outputLine);
           tfCSVLine.append(outputLine+"\n\n\n");

           input1.close();
           input2.close();
           input3.close();
           input4.close();



          }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Changes are that you're blocking the event dispatch thread (not enough context to be sure). Use [SwingWorkers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for long running tasks. You can use the `publish()` and `process()` methods for interim results like the read strings.

Comment: Increase the buffer size of the scanner.

Comment: Seems like the input for the `JTextArea` is coming too fast, hence you can simply add a `Thread.sleep(...)` after calling `append()` as specified in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17759287/1057230) :-)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, your code runs not on the [`EDT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) thread. If it runs, you should move that to the other one.

Then, you can use from that other thread in order to update Swing UI elements:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tfFIXMsg.append( inputLine + "\n\n\n");
        // or whatever swing action you want to perform...
    }
});
```

If you need more sophisticated solutions try using [`SwingWorker`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingWorker) class.

Comment: should this be placed inside the while loop? or outside?

Comment: Inside the while loop. Don't forget to do the computation in another thread!

Answer (score 2):

If you do things like that, they will be executed in EDT(Event Dispatch Thread). You should move your logic  outside of EDT by starting a new `Thread` to allow Swing to repaint UI properly and post updates to UI as following:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // Your Code Here
    }
});
```

Also consider use of `javax.swing.SwingWorker`, `javax.swing.Timer` and take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).